# How to dispatch numerous actions using a single dispatch in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am working on a project and still learning React. So currently, I have the following in my function. I was told that having numerous dispatches like so can cause problems, apart from looking messy and was suggested to create a single dispatch. How would I go about doing that?

```
dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_ARRAY',
      orderItemsArray: newitemsArray,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_NUMBER',
      tickNumber: tickNumber,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_MESSAGE',
      message: orderMessage,
    })
```

Comment: In my opinion the best design choice is to dispatch a single action with type `SOME_NEW_TYPE` and a payload containing all of those properties.  Your reducer would be responsible for updating the three different parts in response to the one action.

Comment: how would I dispatch that action if I am not in a functional component? I know I could do: dispatch(updateAllAction(foo, bar, biz))  if i were in a function, but I have a const component instead.

Comment: A const component is a function component :). It’s just an arrow function.  If you are in a class component you would use ‘connect’ from react-redux.

Answer (score 1):

Use  redux-batched-actions.

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  action2: id => dispatch(Actions.action2(id)),
  action3: id => dispatch(Actions.action3(id)),
  action1: (dateId, attrId) =>
    dispatch(batchActions([
      Actions.action2(dateId),
      Actions.action3(attrId)
    ]))
});
```

When used out of the box without any performance optimisations, there are two primary concerns:
React will re-render multiple times
React Redux will re-evaluate selectors multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Calling `dispatch` on `forEach` should work.

```
const actions = [{
      type: 'UPDATE_ARRAY',
      orderItemsArray: newitemsArray,
    },{
      type: 'UPDATE_NUMBER',
      tickNumber: tickNumber,
    },{
      type: 'UPDATE_MESSAGE',
      message: orderMessage,
    }]

actions.forEach(action => dispatch(action));
```